Understanding the parabolic state of a quantum particle in the infinite square well
Consider a quantum particle in an infinite square well of width $2\pi$. In other words, the Hamiltonian is $H=p^2$, the position variable is restricted to $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ and the wave function satisfies the boundary conditions $\psi(-\pi)=\psi(\pi)=0$.
Is the parabolic function $\psi : [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\psi(x)=N(\pi^2-x^2)$ a valid state of the system?
On the one hand, the overlap between $\psi$ and every energy eigenstate $\psi_n(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(n x)$ evidently vanishes by symmetry. Thus, one might be tempted to conclude that $\psi$ is not a valid state, despite the fact that it is normalizable and satisfies the boundary conditions.
On the other hand, $\psi \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ and choosing a basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ given by $e_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(i n x)$ we obtain
$$\psi = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_n e_n$$
with coefficients which decay like $c_n \sim 1/n^2$. This seems to indicate that $\psi$ is a legitimate state. If, however, we now attempt to compute $\langle \psi | H^2 | \psi \rangle$ we find contradictory results:
(i) In the position basis: $p=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and thus $\langle \psi | H^2 | \psi \rangle = 0$
(ii) In the Fourier basis: $\langle \psi | H^2 | \psi \rangle = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |c_n|^2 n^4 =\infty$
Edit: @creillyucla identified a silly mistake in the energy eigenbasis stated in the question. Redoing the calculation using the correct energy eigenbasis $(\psi_n)_{n\geq 0}$ stated in creillyucla's answer we obtain $\psi=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n \psi_n$, which leads to a similar contradiction:
(i) In the position basis: $p=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and thus $\langle \psi | H^2 | \psi \rangle = 0$
(ii) In the Fourier basis: $\langle \psi | H^2 | \psi \rangle = \sum_{n\geq 0} |a_n|^2 E_n^2 = 8\pi|N|^2$.

What does $N(\pi^2-x^2)$ denote?

@LeeMosher $N$ is a normalization constant, and not a function or so.

Before we can answer the question, we need a little bit more mathematical clarity here. However, we won't be fully rigorous and leave out details which are not of interest for the question.$^\ddagger$
To start, let us note that when discussing the infinite square well potential with the conventions presented here, we consider (following Ref. 3) the Hilbert space $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and the Hamiltonian $H:=- \frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}$
with domain
$$D(H):= \left\{\psi\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])\, \big\lvert\,\psi\in C^2([-\pi,\pi])\, \wedge\, \psi(\pm \pi)=0 \right\} \quad .\tag 1$$
The domain of the squared Hamiltonian $H^2$ in turn is
$$D(H^2):=\left\{\psi\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])\, \big\lvert\,\psi\in C^4([-\pi,\pi])\, \wedge\, \psi(\pm \pi)=0=\psi^{\prime \prime}(\pm \pi) \right\} \quad .\tag 2 $$
This means that expressions like $H\psi$ are well-defined only if $\psi\in D(H)$ and similarly that $H^2\psi$ is well-defined only if $\psi\in D(H^2)$. In fact, this is exactly the crux to realize in order to solve your problem, as discussed below.$^{1,2,3}$
Note that generally, to define an operator means to specify a map and a domain. In particular, the notion of self-adjointness is tightly connected to the domain of an operator. Intro books on quantum mechanics most often ignore these issues. This is fine to a large extent, but the problem you encounter is one of the many instances where you really need to go back to the basic math.

To proceed, we have to define what we mean by expectation value. Assuming you can write the (self-adjoint) observable of interest as
$$A=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n\, |\psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n| \quad ,\tag 3$$
we define the expectation value (with respect to a normalized vector $\psi$) by
$$\langle A\rangle_\psi:=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n \,|\langle \psi_n,\psi\rangle|^2 \tag 4 \quad . $$
Eq. $(4)$ makes sense and is finite if $\psi\in D\left(\sqrt{|A|}\right)$. We also have that $D(A)\subseteq D\left(\sqrt{|A|}\right)$ and if $\psi \in D(A)$, then eq. $(4)$ reduces to the usual and often stated $\langle A\rangle_\psi=\langle \psi, A\psi\rangle$.$^4$
Now to your specific problem: You should realize that your given wave function $\psi$ is not in the domain of the squared Hamiltonian, i.e. it holds that $\psi\not\in D(H^2)$ and hence the inner product $\langle \psi, H^2\psi\rangle$ is of no meaning (even if the corresponding integrals are finite). But it holds that $\psi \in D(H)$, and by our previous considerations you can compute the expectation value via
$$\langle H^2\rangle_\psi=\langle H\psi,H\psi\rangle \quad . \tag 5 $$
The evaluation of the RHS of eq. $(5)$ can be performed in any basis and yields the same result.

$^\ddagger$Remark in response to comments: For example, the Hamiltonian and its square as introduced by $(1)$ and $(2)$ are symmetric but not self-adjoint on their (dense) domain. But due Nelson's criterion, it admits a unique self-adjoint extension, and this is the observable we want to work with (as mentioned already by @Valter Moretti). The extension is simply
$$H_e:=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}E_n \,|\psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n| \tag 6 $$
where the convergence is in the strong operator topology, and $E_n$ and $\psi_n$ denote the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions discussed e.g. in the other answers. The domain is
$$D(H_e):=\left\{  \psi\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])\,\rvert\, \left(E_n\langle \psi_n,\psi\rangle\right)_{n\in\mathbb N} \in\ell^2\right\} \tag 7 \quad .$$
By the spectral theorem, the square follows as
$$ H_e^2:=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}E_n^2\, |\psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n| \tag 8$$
with domain
$$D(H_e^2):=\left\{  \psi\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])\,\rvert\, \left( E_n^2\langle \psi_n,\psi\rangle\right)_{n\in\mathbb N} \in\ell^2\right\} \tag 9 \quad .$$
The argument and conclusion of the above (more accessible) way however do not change: The wave function $\psi$ of interest is not in the domain of $H_e^2$.
References and further reading:

Gieres, François. "Mathematical surprises and Dirac's formalism in quantummechanics." Reports on Progress in Physics (2000). Example 7
Bonneau, Guy, Jacques Faraut, and Galliano Valent. "Self-adjoint extensions of operators and the teaching of quantum mechanics." American Journal of physics (2001). Section 2
Dietrich Grau. Übungsaufgaben zur Quantentheorie. Page 170
Cassinelli, G., and G. Olivieri. "The statistics of unbounded observables in Hilbert-space quantum mechanics." Nuovo Cim. (1984).


This is so good. Also, my answer had your Equation (5) get a disagreement; my answer was originally worded to say that there was no disagreement, and so I was quite confused. Definitely too late last night. Now that I have checked and obtained agreement, things are fine again~

@naturallyInconsistent Glad I could help. Yes, the problems are indeed non-trivial (for us physicists, at least, I'd say), and I thus think the question is of high educational value. As I mentioned in my answer: In QM we often get away by ignoring the rigorous mathematics--this situation is different, however (and there are many more, see ref. 1 for example).

@TobiasFünke: your comment sounds really intriguing to me. It would be awesome if you could incorporate into your answer.

There's a simple error in your $\psi_n$ which is screwing you up. In general, the form of the eigenstates $\psi_n(x;x_o,L)$ for a well of length $L$ starting at $x_o$ is
$$
\psi_n(x;x_o,L) \propto \sin\left(\frac{n\pi (x-x_o)}{L}\right)
$$
So for your case ($L=2\pi$, $x_o=-\pi$) we have
$$
\psi_n(x;-\pi,2\pi) \propto \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \left( x + \pi \right)}{2\pi}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)
$$
which works out to a basis consisting of $\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)$ for $n$ even and $\cos\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)$ for $n$ odd. This resolves your contradiction. The parabolic state you describe has finite overlap with the $\cos\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)$.

Good point @Tobias, once I saw the error in the set-up (all the eigenstates are odd functions w.r.t. reflection about the well center), I did not keep reading. However, OP's question about the "validity" of the state seems independent of its energy expectation value $\langle H \rangle$.

D'oh! Thanks for the catch! Interestingly, however, when I redo the calculation with your corrected energy eigenbasis, it does not solve the issue with the variance being not well-defined!

You are certainly correct that it does not address the $H^2$ issue. My assumption (which appears to be erroneous) was that the observation most troubling OP was the absence of overlap with the eigenbasis, and that resolution of this problem would be sufficient for resolving his question, "Is the parabolic state valid?". I presumed OP would accept that the conflicting results for $\langle H^2 \rangle$ is due to some mathematical technicality, but the lack of overlap is a more major conceptual conflict requiring resolution.

I see. Don't get me wrong, you certainly identified one problem. If you want, consider to expand the answer concerning the other issue and to fully address the question.

@creillyucla I've updated the question to reflect the comments.

I can do that, but I am not familiar enough with these functional analysis issues to do much more than cite the sources the give in your comment.

Barring the (now corrected) mistake of the omission of part of eigenvectors,
the point is quite trivial: here, one is referring to two different notions of energy observable but using the same name!
Different bases of eigenvectors mean different domains and different self-adjoint operators. All that, even if on special common domains (here, the space of smooth functions with support in $(0,L)$), the operators may coincide. In this case, we have a symmetric operator $-(\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x)^2$ on smooth functions supported in $(0,L)$ with two different selfadjoint extensions. The observables are the self-adjoint extensions.
The two (selfadjoint!) Hamiltonians are different observables since their domains and their spectra (permitted energies) are different.
The only physically relevant issue here is the choice of the correct Hamiltonian operator.
Essentially, we have to decide if we are dealing with a 1D lattice (second case, where the discrete momentum operator is defined) or an infinitely rigid  box (first case, where the discrete momentum observable is not defined).
In the case of a lattice, the momentum is the selfadjoint extension of $-i\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$, initially defined on the smooth functions compactly supported in $(0,L)$, with periodic boundary conditions. The parabolic state does not belong to the initial domain. However, to check if it belongs to the true of the selfadjoint extension domain, one has to see if
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} n^2 |\psi_n|^2<+\infty$$
and not if the derivative of $\psi$ is $L^2$ (maybe the two conditions coincide, but it has to be proved). The same argument regarding the expectation value of $P^2$, see below.
In both cases the self-adjointness domain of $H_i$, $i=1,2$, is made of the $L^2$ functions $\psi$ such that
$$\sum_n(E^{(i)}_n)^2 |\psi^{(i)}_n|^2<+\infty$$
with obvious notation.
Notice that the Hilbert spaces of the two cases are identical: $L^2([0,L],\mathrm{d}x)$: the difference is just in the choice of the notion of energy.
Once the notion of energy has been accepted, the issue of physically meaningful states can be addressed. One can assume that the energy content and/or energy standard deviation must be finite. Obviously, for a given state, this depends on the used notion of energy.

Just a comment that the Hamiltonian expressed with respect to both bases actually produces same energy expectation . The issue is with the squared Hamiltonian observable <H^2>.

Ok, so the problem is if states with infinite energy standard deviation are acceptable. This depends on the notion of energy one adopts.

Valter, if I understand you correctly, then I think you misunderstand the question. OP wants to compute for a given (self-adjoint, after choosing appropriate BC) $H$ the expectation value of $H^2$ for their given wave function. The problem is that this wave function is not in the domain of $H^2$, as I noted in my comments under the question.

ah. I found the discussion a bit confused and so you might be right. Perhaps I misinterpreted the question...

Yes, the question is a formulated a bit vaguely, but I really think this is the essence of the question.

What is $H$ in the question? It seemed to me that there are two notions in the play.

One is $P^2$ (correctly intepreted with periodic BC) and the other referes to the considered basis with vanischin BC.

I think they mean the second derivative, and the wave function should vanish at the boundaries (because I think this is what usually is meant by "infinite square well"). See the sources in my comments for a precise definition.

So there is no $P$ here! The issue is just a mismatch of mathematical tools. I tried to correctly introduce a notion of $P$

Yes, indeed -- at least this is how I read the question...

I prefer not deleting my answer and see what happens. I am in Dublin airport waiting for my flight. There is nothing to do here.

Sure, your answer also adds much value to the question/problem. I've written an answer now to reflect how I understood the question.

Let's be clearer with the essence of your problem, now that the other answerer brought to your attention that you were missing the cosines.
Your state is $\left<x|\psi\right>=\sqrt{\frac{15}{16\pi^5}}(\pi^2-x^2)$ and your problem has natural eigenstates
$$\tag1\left<x|n\right>=
\begin{cases}
\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\cos\left(\frac{n+1}2x\right)&,\text{even }n\in\mathbb Z^+_0\\
\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2x\right)&,\text {odd }n\in\mathbb Z^+
\end  {cases}$$
It should then be simple to show that
$$\tag2\left<n|\psi\right>=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{8\sqrt{15}}{\pi^3(n+1)^3}(-1)^{n/2}&,\text{even }n\in\mathbb Z^+_0\\
0&,\text {odd }n\in\mathbb Z^+
\end  {cases}$$
And suddenly your acute problem is gone, because you are wrong that the coefficients go by $n^{-2}$; it instead goes by $n^{-3}$, so that your Fourier sum is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^+_0}\left<\psi|\hat H|n\right>\left<n|\hat H|\psi\right>
\tag3&=\frac{64(15)}{\pi^6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^6}\left(\frac{2k+1}2\right)^4\\
\tag4&=\frac{60}{\pi^6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^2}\\
\tag5&=\frac{60}{\pi^6}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{8}=\frac{15}{2\pi^4}
\end  {align}$$
whereas the equivalent position version is $\left<\psi|\hat H^2|\psi\right>=\dfrac{15}{2\pi^4}$
This is not an answer, as noted by Tobias Fünke; my computation acted the Hamiltonian on bra and ket, in which case the convergence happens to work, whereas the essence of your question is about why acting the Hamiltonian twice on one side leads to unequal values in different bases. I do not know enough functional analysis to answer that, but just wanted to do all these computation for you.

How are you able to post an answer to a closed question? Oo

@TobiasFünke I started work on it long before it got closed.

@TobiasFünke https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/401169

@naturallyInconsistent Thanks. In the edit to the OP you may note that I reached a similar conclusion (albeit different numerically). This still leaves unanswered the original question, however.

P.S. I think the value <\psi, H^2 \psi > = 8\pi I quoted in the OP is indeed correct because it agrees with the position-space calculation of <H\psi, H\psi>.

You should check out my newest edit. Yes, there is agreement, but it is not $8\pi$; you have somewhat consistently ignored the normalisation.

@naturallyInconsistent: yep you’re right, thanks for the correction.

As explained in previous answers, your wave function belongs to the full Hilbert space $L^2$, and the domain of $H$, but not to the domain of $H^2$. In general, unbounded operator (like $H$ or $H^2$) are only defined in a dense subspace, so there is no contradiction, but is rather expected that a generic state is not in the domain.
The issue is that the real space calculation is false. You do not have $H^2|\psi\rangle = 0$ due to issues at the boundary. In fact, just in physical space, you have contradicting results as you could also calculate:
$$
\langle \psi|H^2|\psi\rangle = |H|\psi\rangle|^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}(2N)^2dx = 8\pi N^2
$$
This which agrees with the Fourier series result. Democratically, the first method seems to be wrong.
One way of seeing why is to extend the problem to the entire line by the method of images. The Dirichlet boundary conditions are imposed by imposing antisymmetry at the nodes. Equivalently, just use the definition from the Fourier expansion and let $x\in\mathbb R$ instead of the original domain. You therefore have second order discontinuities at the boundaries and:
$$
\langle x|H^2|\psi\rangle = 4N\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\delta'(x-(2n+1)\pi)
$$
Your original method was almost correct, but you forgot the singular part at the boundary. Now when you calculate the mean value, you do get the correct result. It is precisely at the edge that all the contribution to the final result com from, which is why you were completely off. A more pedestrian approach is to just realise that when integrating by parts, you have a remaining bracket that is important.
In general, the slow decay of the Fourier series come from the discontinuity of the function in real space. In your example the discontinuity is precisely at the boundary, which is why it is not obvious, but is revealed by the images.
